# How to get parent of parent's element in webdriverIO?

Tags: webdriver-io

I am running tests for iPhone safari on browser stack. But click command is not working for iPhone safari on browser stack Selector seems to find an element correctly, but click does nothing and no error,no action ,just silently not executing click.

Same test running perfectly with android device. This is issue with dom structure and I wants to click on parent of parent's element.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried below code snippet and worked for me.

```
const element:WebdriverIO.Element = $('selctor');
let parentEle = element.$('..').$('..');
```

Comment: This is an xpath you are using here. A element found with css followed by two chained elements found using xpaths

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with xpaths using the [xpath axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp), specially ancestor

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

To find the parent elements of input you could use an xpath like

```
browser.$('//input//ancestor::div[1]') //finds div with class=two
browser.$('//input//ancestor::div[2]') //finds div with class=one
```

Sounds like you need

```
browser.$('//input//ancestor::div[2]') //finds div with class=one
```

Comment: Thanks you ! But I don't want to use xpath. we are following only CSS locator strategy.

Comment: $('..') is actually an xpath selector also, not css